# docker-compose up command not responding

Tags: docker

I am using Ubuntu and tried to run Django with Docker.

When I give `docker-compose up` command it give below output

```
Starting aug6_web_1 ... done
Attaching to aug6_web_1
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

and does not print anything else ... for almost 20 min now.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services: 
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
        command: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.0:8000
        volumes: 
            - .:/AUG6
        ports: 
            - '8000:8000'
```

And my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /AUG6
WORKDIR /AUG6
COPY /requirements.txt /AUG6/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /AUG6/
```

*Very first day of learning Docker, excuse if any mistakes*
[image]

Comment: `docker-compose up` will not terminate as long as the containers are running. If you want it to start the containers and then terminate, use `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: I will try that , thanks

Comment: Has your service started and can you access it?

Comment: not started and I can't access it

Comment: I just spotted a mistake in your `runserver` command: you have `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.0:8000` but it should be `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000` or you can remove the IP:PORT completely, as you use the defaults. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker-compose up` will not terminate as long as the containers are running.
If you want it to start the containers and then terminate, use `docker-compose up -d`.

Check the [docker-compose manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

**EDIT 1:**
I just spotted a mistake in your `runserver` command:
You have `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.0:8000` but it should be `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`.
You can remove the IP:PORT completely, as you use the defaults. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver).

Comment: Appreciate the effort, I will try as you suggested